# What is a complete set? Why its useful?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I am learning Discreet Mathematics and while learning Boolean algebra I came across the term **Complete Set**, the prof says that **any formula that can be written with `AND`, `OR` and `NOT` are complete set**. He doesn't explains this term properly or maybe I am new to this but I would love to understand its significance so that I can learn better.

Also, is function and formulas are similar things?

#### Ref

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_9WjWENWV8&t=78m0s

Comment: See [functional completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness).

Comment: The professor actually says "You know that any formula can be written with 'and's, 'or's and 'not's, and therefore they're a complete set". Which is to say that it's the set $\{$and, or, not$\}$ that is complete. A complete set is a set of logical operators that can be used to describe any logical formula. Another example of a complete set is $\{$not, implies$\}$.

Comment: @Arthur you have described formally what is said by the professor but I need some explanation what it means and why its important to know :)